# Could anyone please tell me if "tension" would be appropriate to use in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> Arnold extended a hand, but Bart refused to shake it. Arnold glared at
> him. Bart scowled back. And while all focus was on the **tension**
> between the two of them, no one in the room seemed to have noticed
> that a pair of shoes were peeking out from under the curtain.

Hi. Could anyone please tell me if "tension" would be appropriate to use in this context?

The definitions of it doesn't make it clear to me if it's appropriate. There seems to be different meanings to the word.

Comment: It sounds like those shoes have eyes, though I understand what you are trying to do there. [tension between the two, no need for of them/]. So, in fact, the effect is comical. Perhaps you can use: sticking out, instead.

Comment: Or 'poking out'. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tension) seems clear enough: 2.1 A strained political or social state or relationship.